# MS Dos batch file script to restart IE

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, dos, batch-processing

Looking for MS DOS batch file script to restart Internet explorer. Would highly appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: What is a "batch job"? Is that like a batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start "" taskkill /im iexplore.exe
start "" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" google.com
CLS
EXIT
```

Comment: In case you want to open the IE in full screen mode, add the -k option
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k google.com